# Exporting UTF8 data from db2

Tags: database, db2

I have a db2 table that contains values in many languages (including right-to-left languages.) When I export this table on a linux box using cli's ''export'' command, I get a good looking comma delimited text file (DEL file,) but when I try it on aix, it replaces all characters that are not in ascii with 0x1a.

I tried playing around with LC_LANG and DB2CODEPAGE, no go. I also tried using codepage modifier, but cli said it can't convert between these two codepages (any codepage I tried that is not English.)

I also tried IXF export, and the data is corrupted there as well.

Help! F1!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The codepage of the database has to be set when creating the database. It is not possible to modify it later. You can check the codepage of the database with the following command and look for the value of "**Database code page**":

```
db2 get db cfg for [database_name]
```

Newer AIX versions shouldn't have problems with Unicode, but if you have and older version, that might cause problems too.